# std::regex not matching

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, split

I have a regex which by [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GQKqFl/1) works correctly:

[image]

There are 2 matches, as intended.

Now I'd like to split the same with std's [regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator):

```
const std::string text = "This is a test string [more or less] and here is [another].";

const std::regex ws_re("\(?<=\[)(.*?)(?=\])\gm"); // HOW TO WRITE THE ABOVE REGEX IN HERE?

std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), ws_re, -1),
           std::sregex_token_iterator(),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

This compiles fine, but nothing is printed to stdout.

I think the regex has to be written somehow else, can you please point on my mistake?

Comment: \ must be escaped or Raw string literal should be used.

Comment: Tried with `\\(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=\\])\\gm`. Still nothing is printed.

Comment: Or use a raw string.

Comment: You shouldn't have `\gm` in the regexp.

Comment: Why the first parenthesis is escaped, but other not?

Comment: You specify the flags as the second argument in the constructor, not as characters in the regexp.

Comment: You don't need the `g` flag when creating an iterator. And you don't need the `m` flag if the regexp doesn't have `^` or `$` in it.

Comment: None of the parentheses should be escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
const std::regex ws_re(R"(\[([^\]\[]*)\])");
```

Also, make sure you extract Group 1 values by passing the `1` as the last argument to `std::sregex_token_iterator` instead of `-1` (`-1` is used when splitting).

`R"(\[([^\]\[]*)\])"` is a raw string literal that defines the `\[([^\]\[]*)\]` regex pattern. It matches

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\]\[]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
- `\]` - a `]` char.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/Gx1jJm):

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const std::string text = "This is a test string [more or less] and here is [another].";
    const std::regex ws_re(R"(\[([^\]\[]*)\])");
    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), ws_re, 1),
           std::sregex_token_iterator(),
           std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works, can I somehow use the lookaheads in the regex?

Comment: @Daniel You can use lookaheads, but not lookbehinds, with `std::regex`. Else, use `boost::regex`, then you will be able to use all lookarounds.

Answer (score -3):

You need to escape `\` with `\\`. Also `\gm` and `\` (at the beginning) should be removed to be: `(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=\\])`

Comment: You said `\gm` should be removed, but you didn't remove it.

Comment: oh I see, the parentheses shouldn't be escaped. Can you try: `(?<=\\[)(.*?)(?=\\])`